# Display a tooltip with Html helper

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'd like add a tooltip to my razor view like this :

```
   @Html.Editor("Password", new { Title = "Doit contenir au moins une lettre majuscule, une minuscule, un chiffre et un caractère spécial" })
```

It is not working, If I just change the html helper by the input html tag, it works!!

I need to know :

1. Where is the cause of this error?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: What kind of element does the Editor render into (does this element support a Title attribute?)?

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Display-beautiful-tooltips-in-Asp-Net-MVC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding html attributes using `Html.EditorFor()` and  is only supported in MVC-5.1+. If you do have MVC-5.1, then the correct usage is

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { Title = "Doit contenir ... spécial" }, })
```

Other wise you need to use the `@Html.Password()` or `@Html.PasswordFor()` methods

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { Title = "Doit contenir ... spécial"  })
```

[Refer documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes#Bootstrap)